# Bundle Android outra classe(Adapter)

Tags: android

Boa noite! estou com a seguinte situação :

```
case R.id.item_cep:
    corPadrao = Color.parseColor("#4DC184");
    imgCircle.setColorFilter(corPadrao);
    nomeRoteirizacao.setText("Por Cep");
    setActivityBackgroundColor(corPadrao);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InformarEntrega.class);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("cor","#4DC184");
    intent.putExtras(params);
```

onde ao clicar no `item_cep` ele armazene a cor, só que em outra classe(Classe é Adapter) eu preciso ter essa cor como proceder?

Estou fazendo da forma correta? e como pego essa cor na classe adapter?

Comment: até onde eu sei, o Bundle faz o parse entre activitys (ou fragments) nunca tentei usá-lo para passar um elemento para outra classe. 
Você pode usar uma variável para passar a cor pra classe adapter ou usar o SharedPreferences ou ainda, ter uma model que contenha a string 'cor'e usar esta model para parsear os dados.

Comment: como eu passaria a cor pra  classe ? eu ja tenho a variável  na primeira activity

Answer (score 1):

Diego,

Para resolver seu problema, crie um arquivo chamado colors.xml em values (caso você não possua).

Parecido com isto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="DarkOrange">#FF8C00</color>
 <color name="WhiteSmoke">#F5F5F5</color>
 <color name="Goldenrod">#DAA520</color>
 <color name="LightGrey">#D3D3D3</color>
 <color name="DarkGray">#333333</color>
 <color name="DarkRed">#8B0000</color>
 <color name="Gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="ForestGreen">#228B22</color>
 <color name="Black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Não precisa de um Bundle. Você pude usar no objeto intent o método:

```
intent.putExtra("color", R.color.Gray);
```

Para recuperar, em outra Activity:

```
int resColor =  getIntent().getIntExtra("cor",0);
```

Zero é para o caso de não conseguir recuperar.

Isso te devolverá o inteiro referente a cor na classe R. Bastará você atribuí-la como quiser.

**Edição: Não faz o menor sentido um Intent para uma classe Adapter.**

Att,

Comment: Mateus! o problema que getIntent() ele nao reconhece na classe Adapter!

Comment: @DiegoDiasMól não faz sentido um Intent para uma classe adapter em termos de arquiterura. O que você deseja fazer? Se você usa uma classe que não seja uma activity, instancie e passe no construtor o que deseja. Adapter não é para esse caso "InformarEntrega".

Comment: pq no adapter ele cria os cards, exemplificando: eu clico em uma opção do menu ele altera a cor desses cards! na verdade não é nem o card todo é só um elemento do card

Comment: Crie um método no seu adapter que faça esse trabalho e chame-o, por exemplo changeColor(int elementPosition) e basta você alterar a cor do elemento viewHolder desejado. na propria activity, adapter.changeColor(1); por exemplo.

Comment: public void setActivityBackgroundColor(int color) {
        RelativeLayout titleLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLeft);
        RelativeLayout topLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeTop);
        ArrayList<Pedido> items = Pedido.getTestingList();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            titleLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
            topLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }


    }

Comment: @DiegoDiasMól espero ter ajudado. Quando perguntar, se puder, de detalhes dos requisitos (aquilo que você deseja fazer exatamente, assim podemos te ajudar com mais propriedade). Um abraço e boa sorte!